# Find token in existing cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra

How do we find existing token assigned to cassandra nodes? I have 4 node cluster, how can i identify if nodes are unbalanced? What are values of currently assigned tokens? Is there any command used with nodetool.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "nodetool ring" command. http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsRing.html

It shows all the needed information regarding tokens assignment. It also shows the load under the data directory for each node in the cluster.